# Why pagination shows all the records of the table on every page?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have added pagination as follows to my laravel project. But all the pages display the same content.

Think that there are 8 records in the employee table. When I added the below code, on the first page it displays all 8 records, and on the second page also it displays the same 8 records.

It doesn't break the first 5 records to the first page and last 3 records to the second page.

controller

```
public function all()
{
    $data = DB::table('employees')->paginate(5);
    $employeeshow = employee::all()->toArray();
    return view('employee.index', compact('employeeshow', 'data'));
}
```

index.blade.php

```
  <div>
     <table>
         <tr>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
         </tr>
       @foreach($employeeshow as $row)
         <tr>
           <td>{{$row['firstname']}}</td>
           <td>{{$row['lastname']}}</td>
         </tr>
       @endforeach
     </table>
      {{ $data->links() }}
  </div>
```

I want to display the first 5 records on the first page, next 5 records on the second page likewise. Help me. Thank you

Comment: Everything is ok. I found no reason to show paginate.

Comment: I edited the question with full code. Should I write another foreach to get pagination work properly? @A.ANoman

Comment: Whats about render `{{ $data->render(); }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not make much sense, you are fetching all employees from the database with `$employeeshow` and looping through them, but then you are getting a different set of employees from the database with `$data` and paginate them, so it does not matter which page you open, you are always looping through `$employeeshow` which will always contain the same employees.

I would do the following instead:

Controller:

```
public function all()
{
    $employees = employee::paginate(5); // why is your model lowercase?

    return view('employee.index', compact('employees'));
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($employees as $employee)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $employee->firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->lastname }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {{ $employees->links() }}
</div>
```

You can read more about pagination in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination).

Comment: Where is `$data` ??

Comment: It is not needed anymore, I forgot to update the view properly, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$employeeshow` please try `$data` in your foreach loop.

Your paginated value stored in `$data` not in the `$employeeshow`.